# != not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my prob,

I am trying to validate a variable have value or no using if condition. But it is not working as expected. Here is the code i used,

```
var NextAlbum = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_RelatedPhotos_hdnRelatedAlbum').val();               
if ((NextAlbum != "") || (NextAlbum != "undefined") || (NextAlbum != undefined)) {
window.location.href = NextAlbum;
}
else {
a.slideRun(-1, !0);
}
```

**NextAlbum** shows value as *"undefined"*, but **if block executed rather else**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you put C# as a tag for your question?

Comment: Why not simply `if (NextAlbum)` ?

Comment: ProTip: you can just use `if (NextAlbum)` to check if `NextAlbum` is undefined/null/ any falsy values

Comment: since it is 'OR' if either of the condition is true then the if block will be executed, in this case undefined is != ""

Comment: Have you tries "!==" operator ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `&&` because at any give time atleast one condition will be true.

```
if ((NextAlbum != "") && (NextAlbum != "undefined") && (NextAlbum != undefined))
```

To explain - when you use `||` at any time one of the comparisons is true, the whole comparison is true. Since `NextAlbum = "undefined"` the first comparison is true: `NextAlbum != ""`.

```
true || false = true
false || false = false
```

If you use `&&`, this is reversed; if at any time one comparison is false, all are false.

```
true && false = false
true && true = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (NextAlbum !== undefined)` or `if (NextAlbum === undefined)` as negation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this---

```
typeof NextAlbum != 'undefined'
```

typeof operator will always return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var NextAlbum = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_RelatedPhotos_hdnRelatedAlbum').val();               
if (NextAlbum) {
window.location.href = NextAlbum;
}
else {
a.slideRun(-1, !0);
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var NextAlbum = '#ContentPlaceHolder1_RelatedPhotos_hdnRelatedAlbum').val();               
if (typeof NextAlbum != 'undefined') {
      window.location.href = NextAlbum;
}
else {
      a.slideRun(-1, !0);
}
```

If you are interested to know whether the variable is declared or has the value undefined, then use the `typeof` operator.

```
typeof NextAlbum != 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var NextAlbum = $('#<%= hdnRelatedAlbum.ClientID %>').val();
        if (NextAlbum != null || NextAlbum != '' || NextAlbum != 'undefined' || NextAlbum != undefined)
        {
            window.location.href = NextAlbum;
        }
        else {
            a.slideRun(-1, !0);
        }
```